# Avoid empty tick labels in histogram (lattice)

Tags: r, lattice

I read data from a csv file:

`| proband | stimulus | group |
|---------|----------|-------|
| 0       | A        | X     |
| 0       | B        | Y     |
| 0       | C        | Z     |
| 1       | A        | X     |
| 1       | B        | Y     |
| 1       | C        | N     |`

I'm reading in the csv file and plot a histogram for each stimulus as pdf:

```
Data <- read.csv(file="./groups_data.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";")

library(lattice)
pdf("output/groups_single.pdf", width=8, height=4)
par(mar=c(1.5,0,1,2.5), xpd=TRUE)
bar_plot_single <- histogram(~ group | stimulus, data=Data, layout=c(1,1), xlab="Gruppe", ylab="Häufigkeit (%)", scales=list(x=list(rot=90)))
print(bar_plot_single)
dev.off()
```

When i plot a histogram for each stimulus using lattice i want to avoid empty tick labels (e.g. N, Y, Z in the following image):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a result that fits my needs by using a for loop.

```
Data <- read.csv(file="./groups_data.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";")
stimuli <- factor(unique(Data$stimulus))


library(lattice)
pdf("output/groups_single.pdf", width=8, height=4)
par(mar=c(1.5,0,1,2.5), xpd=TRUE)
for ( i in stimuli ) {
    data <- subset(Data, stimulus == i)
    bar_plot_single <- histogram(~ group | stimulus, 
        data=data, 
        layout=c(1,1),
        ylim=c(0,100),
        xlab="Gruppe", 
        ylab="Häufigkeit (%)", 
        scales=list(x=list(rot=90)),
        panel=function(...){
            panel.abline(h=seq(0,150,20))
            panel.abline(v=seq(0,150,1))
            panel.histogram(...)
        })
    print(bar_plot_single)
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it works with `lattice`'s faceting, but you can just loop manually this way:

```
library(lattice)

dat <- data.frame(proband = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                  stimulus = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                  group = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "N"))

labels <- rbind("", levels(dat$group))

by(dat, dat$stimulus, function(x) {
  histogram(~ group, 
            data = x, 
            layout = c(1,1), 
            xlab = "Gruppe", 
            ylab = "Häufigkeit (%)", 
            ylim = c(-10, 110), 
            scales = list(x=list(rot=90,
                                 labels = labels[cbind(levels(x[, 3]) %in% x[, 3] + 1,
                                                 1:length(levels(x[, 3])))])),
            drop.unused.levels = FALSE) })
```

to specify for each plot the x-axis tick labels.

Saving the returned list object and then

```
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, c(p, nrow = 1))
```

gives plots such as these:

[image]

And to pdf is then also just the same as in your question:

```
pdf("groups_single.pdf", width=8, height=4)
par(mar=c(1.5,0,1,2.5), xpd=TRUE)

by(dat, dat$stimulus, function(x) {
  histogram(~ group, 
            data = x, 
            layout = c(1,1), 
            xlab = "Gruppe", 
            ylab = "Häufigkeit (%)", 
            ylim = c(-10, 110), 
            scales = list(x=list(rot=90,
                                 labels = labels[cbind(levels(x[, 3]) %in% x[, 3] + 1,
                                                       1:length(levels(x[, 3])))])),
            drop.unused.levels = FALSE) })

dev.off()
```

Comment: Maybe a wasn't precise enough in my question. I don't want to remove the labels. I also want to remove empty "levels" (i don't really know the correct term in R).

Comment: As in, `by(dat, dat$stimulus, function(x) {
  histogram(~ group, 
            data = x, 
            layout = c(1,1), 
            xlab = "Gruppe", 
            ylab = "Häufigkeit (%)", 
            ylim = c(-10, 110), 
            scales = list(x=list(rot=90)),
            drop.unused.levels = TRUE) })` this?